# How would I stop a UIImageView being moved around, Using GestureRecongnizers, outside of a UIView?

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer

I'm creating an image Based app and I want the images that are displayed to be rotated/moved/scaled within the UIView that i've created. I followed a useful tutorial online on how to implement UIGestures and I've got the hang of using them I just need to understand the code behind them a bit more so I can retain the gestures within this UIView. here is the Code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
layoutOne = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(95.0, 107.0, 578, 682)];
theImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[layoutOne frame]];
[theImageView setImage:image];
theImageView.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
[layoutOne addSubview:theImageView];
takePhoto.hidden = YES;
theImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
[pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[theImageView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
[rotationRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[theImageView addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
[panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[theImageView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

UITapGestureRecognizer *deleteButton = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(delButton:)];
[deleteButton setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[deleteButton setDelegate:self];
[theImageView addGestureRecognizer:deleteButton];


UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[tapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:deleteButton];
[theImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[self.view addSubview:theImageView];
}
```

**NOTE**

```
UIImage *image;
UIImageView *theImageView;
UIView *layoutOne;
```

Those are my declared Gesture Recognisers and below is another part of the tutorial I followed to get them to do their jobs:

```
-(void)scale:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"See a pinch gesture");
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];

if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    lastScale = 1.0;
    return;
}

CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]);

CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);

[[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];

lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];
}

-(void)rotate:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"See a rotate gesture");
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];    

    if([(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        lastRotation = 0.0;
        return;
    }

CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (lastRotation - [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation]);

CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform,rotation);

[[(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];

lastRotation = [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)sender rotation];
}

-(void)move:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"See a move gesture");
    [[(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender view] layer];//removeAllAnimations];

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];
CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];

if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

    firstX = [[sender view] center].x;
    firstY = [[sender view] center].y;


}


translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY+translatedPoint.y);

[[sender view] setCenter:translatedPoint];
if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    CGFloat finalX = translatedPoint.x + (.35*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.view].x);
    CGFloat finalY = translatedPoint.y + (.35*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.view].y);

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {

        if(finalX < 0) {

            finalX = 0;
        }

        else if(finalX > 768) {

            finalX = 768;
        }

        if(finalY < 0) {

            finalY = 0;
        }

        else if(finalY > 1024) {

            finalY = 1024;
        }
    }

    else {

        if(finalX < 0) {

            finalX = 0;
        }

        else if(finalX > 1024) {

            finalX = 768;
        }

        if(finalY < 0) {

            finalY = 0;
        }

        else if(finalY > 768) {

            finalY = 1024;
        }
    }
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.35];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
    [[sender view] setCenter:CGPointMake(finalX, finalY)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

}
```

Sorry about the long lines of the code I just want to make sure that you understand exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I want to better understand the Maths thats going on within mainly the `-(void)move:(id)sender` so I might be able to stop the UIImage/UIImageView from moving outside the UI subview (layoutOne) that I've created. If you might be able help me that would be really appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do this with the method I used above. It was really easy once I figured out what I needed to do. If your using this method above yourself, all you need to do is make sure the `UIView` your using in this case mine is called `layoutOne`. In the `move:`, `rotate:`, `scale:` methods you need to add in `layoutOne.clipsToBounds = YES;` making sure that it's not within any of the `if`, `else if`, `else` statements. This should keep the image you wish to interact with doesn't move outside the `UIView` instead if it touches the bounds of the View those parts of the image will not appear. Simples!